# closed other buttons while click on one of them

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

i just searched about this nut i didn't find anything.
so i have 5 buttons that when you clicked on them it shows a paragraph and if you click again it will hide that.but i wonder that how can i make buttons like when you opened one button and click on the other button it will closed the rest of the buttons.i mean i want to hide the other buttons while one of them is clicked and opened.
and i would appreciate that if you tell me a better way for make this codes smaller.
this is an image of the whole page:
https://uupload.ir/files/0xwx_desktop-design.jpg
you can see the list on right,so i want it to be like when i clicked on one the arrow icons the other will closed and hide content.
this is an example from one of the buttons code,HTML Code:

```
       <ul>
        <h1>FAQ</h1>
        <li>
            
            <button type="button" id="arrowbtn1">
                <span id="span1">How many team members can I invite?</span>
                <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="arrow down icon" id="arrowimage1" class="arrowimage">
            </button>
            <p id="p1">
                You can invite up to 2 additional users on the<br>
                Free plan.There is no limit on team members for <br>
                the Premium plan.
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="button" id="arrowbtn2">
                <span id="span2">What is the maximum file upload size?</span>
                <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="arrow down icon" id="arrowimage2" class="arrowimage">
            </button>
            <p id="p2">
                No more than 2GB. All files in your account must<br>
                fit your allotted storage space.
            </p>
        </li>

        <li>
            <button type="button" id="arrowbtn3">
                <span id="span3">How do I reset my password?</span>
                <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="arrow down icon" id="arrowimage3" class="arrowimage">
            </button>
            <p id="p3">
                Click “Forgot password” from the login page or<br>
                “Change password” from your profile page.<br>
                A reset link will be emailed to you
            </p>
        </li>

        <li>
            <button type="button" id="arrowbtn4">
                <span id="span4">Can I cancel my subscription?</span>
                <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="arrow down icon" id="arrowimage4" class="arrowimage">
            </button>
            <p id="p4">
                Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your<br>
                request no questions asked.
            </p>
        </li>

        <li>
            <button type="button" id="arrowbtn5">
                <span id="span5">Do you provide additional support?</span>
                <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="arrow down icon" id="arrowimage5" class="arrowimage">
            </button>
            <p id="p5">
                Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone<br>
                lines are open during normal business hours.
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS Code:

```
      ul {
        width: fit-content;
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        right: 60px;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    h1 {
        position: relative;
        left: -40px;
        color: hsl(238, 29%, 16%);
    }
    li {
        width: 400px;
        position: relative;
        left: -40px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        color: hsl(240, 6%, 50%);
        border-bottom: 2px solid hsl(240, 5%, 91%);
    }
    button {
        width: 100%;
        height: 25px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        background-color: inherit;
        color:hsl(240, 6%, 50%);
    }
    button:hover {
        color: hsl(14, 88%, 65%);
    }
    span {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
    .arrowimage {
        float: right;
        padding-top: 5px;
    }
    p {
        margin-top: 0;
        display: none;
        line-height: 25px;
        
    }
```

Js Code :

```
       <script>

        document.getElementById("arrowbtn1").onclick = arrow1;
        document.getElementById("arrowbtn2").onclick = arrow2;
        document.getElementById("arrowbtn3").onclick = arrow3;
        document.getElementById("arrowbtn4").onclick = arrow4;
        document.getElementById("arrowbtn5").onclick = arrow5;

        var arrowstatus = 1;

        function arrow1 () {
            if (arrowstatus == 1) {
                document.getElementById("p1").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("span1").style.fontWeight = "bold";
                document.getElementById("span1").style.color = "hsl(238, 29%, 16%)";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage1").style.transform = "scaley(-1)";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage1").style.marginTop = "5px";
                document.getElementById("arrowbtn2").s = 0;
                arrowstatus = 0;
            } else if (arrowstatus == 0){
                document.getElementById("p1").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("span1").style.fontWeight = "normal";
                document.getElementById("span1").style.color = "inherit";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage1").style.transform = "scaley(1)";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage1").style.marginTop = "0px";;
                arrowstatus = 1;
            }
        }

        function arrow2 () {
            if (arrowstatus == 1) {
                document.getElementById("p2").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("span2").style.fontWeight = "bold";
                document.getElementById("span2").style.color = "hsl(238, 29%, 16%)";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage2").style.transform = "scaley(-1)";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage2").style.marginTop = "5px";
                arrowstatus = 0;
            } else if (arrowstatus == 0){
                document.getElementById("p2").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("span2").style.fontWeight = "normal";
                document.getElementById("span2").style.color = "inherit";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage2").style.transform = "scaley(1)";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage2").style.marginTop = "0px";;
                arrowstatus = 1;
            }
        }

        function arrow3 () {
            if (arrowstatus == 1) {
                document.getElementById("p3").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("span3").style.fontWeight = "bold";
                document.getElementById("span3").style.color = "hsl(238, 29%, 16%)";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage3").style.transform = "scaley(-1)";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage3").style.marginTop = "5px";
                arrowstatus = 0;
            } else if (arrowstatus == 0){
                document.getElementById("p3").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("span3").style.fontWeight = "normal";
                document.getElementById("span3").style.color = "inherit";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage3").style.transform = "scaley(1)";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage3").style.marginTop = "0px";;
                arrowstatus = 1;
            }
        }

        function arrow4 () {
            if (arrowstatus == 1) {
                document.getElementById("p4").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("span4").style.fontWeight = "bold";
                document.getElementById("span4").style.color = "hsl(238, 29%, 16%)";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage4").style.transform = "scaley(-1)";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage4").style.marginTop = "5px";
                arrowstatus = 0;
            } else if (arrowstatus == 0){
                document.getElementById("p4").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("span4").style.fontWeight = "normal";
                document.getElementById("span4").style.color = "inherit";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage4").style.transform = "scaley(1)";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage4").style.marginTop = "0px";;
                arrowstatus = 1;
            }
        }

        function arrow5 () {
            if (arrowstatus == 1) {
                document.getElementById("p5").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("span5").style.fontWeight = "bold";
                document.getElementById("span5").style.color = "hsl(238, 29%, 16%)";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage5").style.transform = "scaley(-1)";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage5").style.marginTop = "5px";
                arrowstatus = 0;
            } else if (arrowstatus == 0){
                document.getElementById("p5").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("span5").style.fontWeight = "normal";
                document.getElementById("span5").style.color = "inherit";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage5").style.transform = "scaley(1)";
                document.getElementById("arrowimage5").style.marginTop = "0px";;
                arrowstatus = 1;
            }
        }
        

    </script>
```

Comment: I only see one `<button>` in the HTML in your question..?

Comment: Did you try applying `display: none` style to the other buttons when the one is clicked? Or is the issue that you can't figure out how to fire logic from clicking a button?

Comment: Are you allowed to use jQuery?

Comment: i tried display:none but it didn't work well,i need a way that can close the button and hide its content and i want to do this with JS ,not JQuery

Comment: You will need to post more information about your problem, then, because we cannot help based on the code you have given us.

Answer (score 3):

Let CSS handle the styling and leave javascript the responsibility of adding and removing that class

```js
//Find all button elements in an element with the id "faq" and iterate them
document.querySelectorAll('#faq button').forEach(item => {
  //Add a on click event handler to each element
  item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    //Get parent element
    let parent = this.parentNode;

    //get current section with class="active"
    let active = document.querySelector("#faq .active");

    //Toggle active state class on parent
    parent.classList.toggle("active");

    //Remove the active class if not on clicked buttons parent.
    if (active && parent != active) {
      active.classList.remove("active");
    }

  });
});
```

```css
#faq {
  list-style-type: none;
}


/*Hide anyting in inactive sections that are not buttons*/

#faq>:not(.active)> :not(button) {
  display: none;
}


/*Style the active button span*/

#faq>.active button>span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: hsl(238, 29%, 16%);
}


/*Style the active button image*/

#faq>.active button>img {
  transform: scaleY(-1);
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- H1 not a valid child of ul -->
<h1>FAQ</h1>
<ul id="faq">

  <li>

    <button type="button" id="arrowbtn1">
                <span id="span1">How many team members can I invite?</span>
                <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="arrow down icon" id="arrowimage1" class="arrowimage">
            </button>
    <p id="p1">
      You can invite up to 2 additional users on the<br> Free plan.There is no limit on team members for <br> the Premium plan.
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" id="arrowbtn2">
                <span id="span2">What is the maximum file upload size?</span>
                <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="arrow down icon" id="arrowimage2" class="arrowimage">
            </button>
    <p id="p2">
      No more than 2GB. All files in your account must<br> fit your allotted storage space.
    </p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button type="button" id="arrowbtn3">
                <span id="span3">How do I reset my password?</span>
                <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="arrow down icon" id="arrowimage3" class="arrowimage">
            </button>
    <p id="p3">
      Click “Forgot password” from the login page or<br> “Change password” from your profile page.<br> A reset link will be emailed to you
    </p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button type="button" id="arrowbtn4">
                <span id="span4">Can I cancel my subscription?</span>
                <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="arrow down icon" id="arrowimage4" class="arrowimage">
            </button>
    <p id="p4">
      Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your<br> request no questions asked.
    </p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button type="button" id="arrowbtn5">
                <span id="span5">Do you provide additional support?</span>
                <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="arrow down icon" id="arrowimage5" class="arrowimage">
            </button>
    <p id="p5">
      Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone<br> lines are open during normal business hours.
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry but I think that the paragraph is not closing when you click on the button again try using `parent.classList.toggle("active")` this way when the button is clicked again then the paragraph is closed.

Comment: @DragonSoup, good spot, I missed that requirement. Fixed with a minor tweak to the logic.

Comment: @JonP i didn't understand your code its a little complicated for me as junior:(and i use that display:none in css but i just didn't put it in question box.

Comment: @JonP i edited the question box and put all codes relative to button and list.so i appreciated that if you can help me with my code.

Comment: @erfanmashari is it the javascript or CSS you have trouble getting your head around? If the javascript, what specific bit? The script itself fairly simple, it just adds the `active` css class from the parent element of the button that was clicked and removes that class from any elements that previously had it.