# Command to hide button content

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I just searched about this, but I didn't find anything. So, I have 5 buttons that when you click on them, it shows a paragraph. If you click again it will hide that. I wonder how can I make buttons like: when you clicked on a button, it will show that button content and hide the content of the another buttons (if they are showing).

If you can, tell me the answer with my code, not another complicated code. I would appreciate that if you tell me a better way for make this codes sum up.

This is an image of the whole page: https://uupload.ir/files/0xwx_desktop-design.jpg. You can see the list on right. I want it to be like when I clicked on one the arrow icons the other contents will hide. This is an example from one of the buttons code:

```js
document.getElementById("arrowbtn1").onclick = arrow1;
document.getElementById("arrowbtn2").onclick = arrow2;
document.getElementById("arrowbtn3").onclick = arrow3;
document.getElementById("arrowbtn4").onclick = arrow4;
document.getElementById("arrowbtn5").onclick = arrow5;

var arrowstatus = 1;

function arrow1 () {
    if (arrowstatus == 1) {
        document.getElementById("p1").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("span1").style.fontWeight = "bold";
        document.getElementById("span1").style.color = "hsl(238, 29%, 16%)";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage1").style.transform = "scaley(-1)";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage1").style.marginTop = "5px";
        document.getElementById("arrowbtn2").s = 0;
        arrowstatus = 0;
    } else if (arrowstatus == 0){
        document.getElementById("p1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("span1").style.fontWeight = "normal";
        document.getElementById("span1").style.color = "inherit";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage1").style.transform = "scaley(1)";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage1").style.marginTop = "0px";;
        arrowstatus = 1;
    }
}

function arrow2 () {
    if (arrowstatus == 1) {
        document.getElementById("p2").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("span2").style.fontWeight = "bold";
        document.getElementById("span2").style.color = "hsl(238, 29%, 16%)";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage2").style.transform = "scaley(-1)";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage2").style.marginTop = "5px";
        arrowstatus = 0;
    } else if (arrowstatus == 0){
        document.getElementById("p2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("span2").style.fontWeight = "normal";
        document.getElementById("span2").style.color = "inherit";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage2").style.transform = "scaley(1)";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage2").style.marginTop = "0px";;
        arrowstatus = 1;
    }
}

function arrow3 () {
    if (arrowstatus == 1) {
        document.getElementById("p3").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("span3").style.fontWeight = "bold";
        document.getElementById("span3").style.color = "hsl(238, 29%, 16%)";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage3").style.transform = "scaley(-1)";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage3").style.marginTop = "5px";
        arrowstatus = 0;
    } else if (arrowstatus == 0){
        document.getElementById("p3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("span3").style.fontWeight = "normal";
        document.getElementById("span3").style.color = "inherit";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage3").style.transform = "scaley(1)";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage3").style.marginTop = "0px";;
        arrowstatus = 1;
    }
}

function arrow4 () {
    if (arrowstatus == 1) {
        document.getElementById("p4").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("span4").style.fontWeight = "bold";
        document.getElementById("span4").style.color = "hsl(238, 29%, 16%)";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage4").style.transform = "scaley(-1)";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage4").style.marginTop = "5px";
        arrowstatus = 0;
    } else if (arrowstatus == 0){
        document.getElementById("p4").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("span4").style.fontWeight = "normal";
        document.getElementById("span4").style.color = "inherit";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage4").style.transform = "scaley(1)";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage4").style.marginTop = "0px";;
        arrowstatus = 1;
    }
}

function arrow5 () {
    if (arrowstatus == 1) {
        document.getElementById("p5").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("span5").style.fontWeight = "bold";
        document.getElementById("span5").style.color = "hsl(238, 29%, 16%)";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage5").style.transform = "scaley(-1)";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage5").style.marginTop = "5px";
        arrowstatus = 0;
    } else if (arrowstatus == 0){
        document.getElementById("p5").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("span5").style.fontWeight = "normal";
        document.getElementById("span5").style.color = "inherit";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage5").style.transform = "scaley(1)";
        document.getElementById("arrowimage5").style.marginTop = "0px";;
        arrowstatus = 1;
    }
}
```

```css
  ul {
    width: fit-content;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 60px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
h1 {
    position: relative;
    left: -40px;
    color: hsl(238, 29%, 16%);
}
li {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    left: -40px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    color: hsl(240, 6%, 50%);
    border-bottom: 2px solid hsl(240, 5%, 91%);
}
button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: inherit;
    color:hsl(240, 6%, 50%);
}
button:hover {
    color: hsl(14, 88%, 65%);
}
span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.arrowimage {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
p {
    margin-top: 0;
    display: none;
    line-height: 25px;
    
}
```

```html
   <ul>
    <h1>FAQ</h1>
    <li>
        
        <button type="button" id="arrowbtn1">
            <span id="span1">How many team members can I invite?</span>
            <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="arrow down icon" id="arrowimage1" class="arrowimage">
        </button>
        <p id="p1">
            You can invite up to 2 additional users on the<br>
            Free plan.There is no limit on team members for <br>
            the Premium plan.
        </p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button type="button" id="arrowbtn2">
            <span id="span2">What is the maximum file upload size?</span>
            <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="arrow down icon" id="arrowimage2" class="arrowimage">
        </button>
        <p id="p2">
            No more than 2GB. All files in your account must<br>
            fit your allotted storage space.
        </p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <button type="button" id="arrowbtn3">
            <span id="span3">How do I reset my password?</span>
            <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="arrow down icon" id="arrowimage3" class="arrowimage">
        </button>
        <p id="p3">
            Click “Forgot password” from the login page or<br>
            “Change password” from your profile page.<br>
            A reset link will be emailed to you
        </p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <button type="button" id="arrowbtn4">
            <span id="span4">Can I cancel my subscription?</span>
            <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="arrow down icon" id="arrowimage4" class="arrowimage">
        </button>
        <p id="p4">
            Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your<br>
            request no questions asked.
        </p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <button type="button" id="arrowbtn5">
            <span id="span5">Do you provide additional support?</span>
            <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="arrow down icon" id="arrowimage5" class="arrowimage">
        </button>
        <p id="p5">
            Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone<br>
            lines are open during normal business hours.
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [closed other buttons while click on one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67118233/closed-other-buttons-while-click-on-one-of-them)

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty fix would be to close them all then open the one the person clicked on.
Some pseudo code would be:

```
function Closeall() 
{
    //closes them all
}

function ClickedButton1() 
{
    Closeall()
    //show data for this button
}
function ClickedButton2() 
{
    Closeall()
    //show data for the second button
}
```

Some not dirty code would be to iterate through an array

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works with your existing codebase and some minor alterations.

To summarize what I included, I changed your **arrowstatus** variable to be an array that monitors the states of each arrow individually, rather than using the variable for all 5 arrows.

A function is called on every button click that I provided at the bottom that calls every arrowx() function **except** the one that you clicked.

Example: If you click arrow1, arrow2(), arrow3(), arrow4(), and arrow5() all get called but arrow1() does not. This prevents an infinite recursion where the new function calls itself.

```js
document.getElementById("arrowbtn1").onclick = arrow1;
document.getElementById("arrowbtn2").onclick = arrow2;
document.getElementById("arrowbtn3").onclick = arrow3;
document.getElementById("arrowbtn4").onclick = arrow4;
document.getElementById("arrowbtn5").onclick = arrow5;

var arrowstatus = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

function arrow1() {
  unclickOtherArrows(1)
  if (arrowstatus[0] == 1) {
    document.getElementById("p1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("span1").style.fontWeight = "bold";
    document.getElementById("span1").style.color = "hsl(238, 29%, 16%)";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage1").style.transform = "scaley(-1)";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage1").style.marginTop = "5px";
    document.getElementById("arrowbtn2").s = 0;
    arrowstatus[0] = 0;
  } else if (arrowstatus[0] == 0) {
    document.getElementById("p1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("span1").style.fontWeight = "normal";
    document.getElementById("span1").style.color = "inherit";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage1").style.transform = "scaley(1)";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage1").style.marginTop = "0px";
    arrowstatus[0] = 1;
  }
}

function arrow2() {
  unclickOtherArrows(2)
  if (arrowstatus[1] == 1) {
    document.getElementById("p2").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("span2").style.fontWeight = "bold";
    document.getElementById("span2").style.color = "hsl(238, 29%, 16%)";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage2").style.transform = "scaley(-1)";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage2").style.marginTop = "5px";
    arrowstatus[1] = 0;
  } else if (arrowstatus[1] == 0) {
    document.getElementById("p2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("span2").style.fontWeight = "normal";
    document.getElementById("span2").style.color = "inherit";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage2").style.transform = "scaley(1)";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage2").style.marginTop = "0px";
    arrowstatus[1] = 1;
  }
}

function arrow3() {
  unclickOtherArrows(3)
  if (arrowstatus[2] == 1) {
    document.getElementById("p3").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("span3").style.fontWeight = "bold";
    document.getElementById("span3").style.color = "hsl(238, 29%, 16%)";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage3").style.transform = "scaley(-1)";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage3").style.marginTop = "5px";
    arrowstatus[2] = 0;
  } else if (arrowstatus[2] == 0) {
    document.getElementById("p3").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("span3").style.fontWeight = "normal";
    document.getElementById("span3").style.color = "inherit";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage3").style.transform = "scaley(1)";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage3").style.marginTop = "0px";
    arrowstatus[2] = 1;
  }
}

function arrow4() {
  unclickOtherArrows(4)
  if (arrowstatus[3] == 1) {
    document.getElementById("p4").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("span4").style.fontWeight = "bold";
    document.getElementById("span4").style.color = "hsl(238, 29%, 16%)";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage4").style.transform = "scaley(-1)";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage4").style.marginTop = "5px";
    arrowstatus[3] = 0;
  } else if (arrowstatus[3] == 0) {
    document.getElementById("p4").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("span4").style.fontWeight = "normal";
    document.getElementById("span4").style.color = "inherit";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage4").style.transform = "scaley(1)";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage4").style.marginTop = "0px";
    arrowstatus[3] = 1;
  }
}

function arrow5() {
unclickOtherArrows(5)
  if (arrowstatus[4] == 1) {
    document.getElementById("p5").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("span5").style.fontWeight = "bold";
    document.getElementById("span5").style.color = "hsl(238, 29%, 16%)";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage5").style.transform = "scaley(-1)";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage5").style.marginTop = "5px";
    arrowstatus[4] = 0;
  } else if (arrowstatus[4] == 0) {
    document.getElementById("p5").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("span5").style.fontWeight = "normal";
    document.getElementById("span5").style.color = "inherit";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage5").style.transform = "scaley(1)";
    document.getElementById("arrowimage5").style.marginTop = "0px";
    arrowstatus[4] = 1;
  }
}

function unclickOtherArrows(currentArrow) {
  if (!(currentArrow === 1) && arrowstatus[0] === 0) arrow1();
  if (!(currentArrow === 2) && arrowstatus[1] === 0) arrow2();
  if (!(currentArrow === 3) && arrowstatus[2] === 0) arrow3();
  if (!(currentArrow === 4) && arrowstatus[3] === 0) arrow4();
  if (!(currentArrow === 5) && arrowstatus[4] === 0) arrow5();
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off the `<button>` tag should not have divs nested within them, just change the buttons to DIVS. [Buttons](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element) should only contain phrasing content. [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2)

There is no need to do this statically as you are in your question. Set up your HTML so this can be done dynamically using ***classes***. You have all the same elements in each section. You can build a function that passes in the clicking element selector, then work off that using parent and sibling elements relative to the current element being clicked, `e.target`. *This allows you to reduce the amount of JS code drastically from what you have.*

```js
const questions = document.querySelectorAll('.question')

const showContent = (el) => {
  el.forEach(question => {
    question.addEventListener('click', (e) => {      
      let $par = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.children[1]
      let $arrow = e.target.parentNode.children[1]
      $par.classList.toggle('hidden')
      e.target.classList.toggle('bold')
      if (!$par.classList.contains('hidden')) {
        $arrow.classList.add('up')
        $arrow.classList.remove('down')
      } else {
        $arrow.classList.add('down')
        $arrow.classList.remove('up')
      }
    })
  })
}

showContent(questions);
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  min-height: 500px;
}

li {
  width: 350px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: hsl(238, 29%, 16%);
}

.question:hover {
  color: hsl(14, 88%, 65%);
}

.par {
  width: 325px;
}

.question {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: hsl(240, 6%, 50%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid hsl(240, 5%, 91%);
  position: relative;
}

.arrow {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}

.up {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <h1>FAQ</h1>
  <li>
    <div class="question">
      <span class="span">How many team members can I invite?</span>
      <i class="arrow down"></i>
    </div>
    <p class="par hidden">
      You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="question">
      <span class="span">What is the maximum file upload size?</span>
      <i class="arrow down"></i>
    </div>
    <p class="par hidden">
      No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.
    </p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="question">
      <span class="span">How do I reset my password?</span>
      <i class="arrow down"></i>
    </div>
    <p class="par hidden">
      Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from your profile page. A reset link will be emailed to you.
    </p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="question">
      <span class="span">Can I cancel my subscription?</span>
      <i class="arrow down"></i>
    </div>
    <p class="par hidden">
      Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions asked.
    </p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="question">
      <span class="span">Do you provide additional support?</span>
      <i class="arrow down"></i>
    </div>
    <p class="par hidden">
      Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business hours.
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```